# Can I post a file directly to Google Drive through email?

Tags: gmail, google-drive

Is there a way to send files directly to Google drive from Gmail?

Comment: Are you talking about sending email to a special address and having the attachment automatically be added to your Google Drive, or are you talking about saving an attachment to Google Drive while you're reading your email in the Gmail client? If the latter, it's part of the normal "download" option if you're using Chrome. If the former, then there's nothing native; you'll need to use something like an [IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/79979).

Answer (score 1):

Google itself does not provide any such facility. Anyhow, what you are asking is completely possible by using ifttt.com.

Comment: IFTTT is a great tool (one of my favorites, in fact), but this is not an answer. _How_ would one do this with IFTTT? Please describe a recipe or at least the triggers and channels needed.

Comment: Any number of IFTTT recipes using [Gmail as a trigger to Google Drive](https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=gmail+google+drive) will allow you to send email contents or attachments directly to Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup a service to provide such a feature very simply: https://www.emailitin.com/ - just click Sign In, link your Google Drive account, and you'll be given a custom email address to use for this purpose.

Comment: similar to this : www.kwikkel.com

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Zappier as "glue" between your email inbox and Google Drive
https://zapier.com/blog/email-to-google-drive/